# DVD Drive is not detected in Windows 8 after upgrading from Windows 7

Tags: windows-8

I have an Acer Aspire 5745g notebook.

Last week I upgraded my operating system from Windows 7 Home Premium to Windows 8 Pro. Unfortunately, after upgrading I can no longer see my DVD-ROM in a list of all devices.

How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Your DVD ROM has an exclamation mark i.e. error. Double click and tell us what error Windows is reporting

Comment: right click and update drivers .... try this ..update from internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I have Samsung Notebook NP350E5C-SO1IN which is a year old. My DVD drive did not show up on my computer. As I searched for a solution on the internet, I came to know that the problem must be due to Windows 8.1. I tried all the fixes suggested by Microsoft including changes in the registry, checking disk manager (Under DVD icon TSSTcorp CDDVDW SN-208BB which was greyed out, properties showed error 45) for three days but to no avail. That was frustrating. Thought for going to the service center and spend some extra bucks for repair.

Today, I used the support center and did a diagnosis. It showed only one problem (error: boot speed slow). I clicked on the error to resolve it and it showed (Superfetch auto fixing. Enable superfetch to make boot and application speed faster). I shut down the PC as I had to go out for a few minutes. Later, when I switched it on, after a few minutes a popup showed up at the bottom near the hidden icon (sata unknown disk removed) and heard the similar purr of the DVD drive.

I checked out ‘My computer’ and the ‘DVD RW’ icon had showed up. I played a cd and it works fine. Hope it stays that way.

I would request all IT geeks to explain what had gone wrong with my pc and how the problem was solved.

Answer (score -1):

[See this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982116), not specific for W8 but should help you solve the issue.

.

[image]

.

**The Fixit software may or may not run or solve the issue in W8, if this is the case, use the "Let me fix it myself" section of the article.**

[image]

.

**Last steps if the problem is not resolved:**

[image]